# ASMX web service with digest auth and validate user credentials against db

Tags: c#, soap, asmx, digest-authentication

i heard when we use digest auth then iis validate user credential again windows active directory. suppose when we design web service for external client then there would be no credential will be there in our windows active directory. people would suggest me to use web service with custom auth like using soap header but the problem is with soap header user credentials travel as plain text from client to service end which i do not want and for digest auth user credentials travel as MD5 hash which is bit secured.

so any way exist to use digest auth but credentials will be validated against db store which i will do ?

please redirect me to right direction and if possible guide me with code.
thanks

Comment: since your customers will be hitting the site outside of the DMZ 1. they will never be part of your AD so internal users no problem 2nd if you have customers hitting a site outside your DMZ your best bet would be to use a Token or Key where they could access the web service or create a specific Numeric or Alpha numeric User Id / Password for them  or get with your network / system admin to help you with this

Comment: when outside customer will provide token then attacker steal that token and they can also send the request to web service how could i protect web service from attacker?

Comment: can we create user account in our windows for out side customer? does it works ?

Comment: you could however depending on how your network is configured if they can't reach your internal site from outside the FireWall then it's pointless I would suggest you get with someone internally in your organization or hire a consultant to set this up for you. think about `Security`

Comment: http://www.rassoc.com/gregr/weblog/2002/07/09/web-services-security-http-digest-authentication-without-active-directory/